# How can I find blocks of the same (or very similar) text in a set of documents

Tags: algorithm

I have various text documents (many from OCR).  Many of these documents have medium/large sections which are entirely the same and which I would like to exclude before doing analysis on them.

I've done a good bit of searching without much luck.  There are some things out there that use regularity of HTML documents' DOM structures, but I'm not working with HTML.  Is there an algorithm out there I can use or a paper that I can read to figure out how to find blocks of the same text across different documents?

Comment: You are likely to be spending as much effort finding such duplicates as you would save by whatever process you want to put the text through.  Do you have an idea of the minimum size of the text that is relevant?

Comment: Are you looking for a DIFF-like algorithm (e.g. https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/) or a more approximate hashing-type algorithm (e.g. https://insideops.wordpress.com/2015/07/30/similarity-search-and-hashing-for-text-documents/)

Comment: I'm not concerned about the amount of time my text analysis is taking as I am that I'm inputting junk into my analysis which isn't relevant to what I'm trying to find.  I had thought of diff and thought it might not be appropriate, but maybe I can look for what percentage of a document isn't different by looking at what percentage is different.  I'll definitely take a look over the similarity search post as well, thanks!